# Python Look-And-Say Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex for the [Look-and-Say](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence) sequence in python. The idea is to split a given string into same-digit substrings. With trial and error, I have `'((\d)\\2*)'`.

For the pattern `11244455221116` this gives `[('11', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('444', '4'), ('55', '5'), ('22', '2'), ('111', '1'), ('6', '6')]` as expected. This works, but looks clumsy. Is there a cleaner way to do this, with or without regex?

Comment: Why it looks clumsy? It's a straight forward and quite simple regex.

Comment: Regex looks good to me -- the alternative (list comprehensions) would be clunkier, imho.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools as IT

text = '11244455221116'
print([(''.join(group), key) for key, group in IT.groupby(text)])
```

yields

```
[('11', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('444', '4'), ('55', '5'), ('22', '2'), ('111', '1'), ('6', '6')]
```

But `re.findall` is faster:

```
In [67]: %timeit [(''.join(group), key)for key, group in IT.groupby(text*100)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 528 us per loop

In [68]: %timeit re.findall(r'((\d)\2*)', text*100)
1000 loops, best of 3: 219 us per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of splitting your string, you can do a replace with a lambda function:

```
re.sub(r'(\d)\1*', lambda x: str(len(x.group(0)))+x.group(1), '112224355')
```

result: `2132141325`